# Rspec failing with load_missing_constant when classes live in subdirectories and are subclassed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm having some troubles running a bunch of RSpec tests due to something I suspect is related to autoloading.  Here is the error:

```
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:490:in `load_missing_constant': Expected /var/lib/jenkins/.../portfolios/base_manage_controller.rb to define Portfolios::BaseManageController (LoadError)
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `block in const_missing'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
from /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/.../app/controllers/portfolios/customize_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Here is the header of the file:

```
class Portfolios::BaseManageController < ApplicationController
```

And it lives in `app/controllers/portfolios/base_manage_controller.rb`

And its subclass:

```
class Portfolios::CustomizeController < Portfolios::BaseManageController
```

And it lives in `app/controllers/portfolios/customize_controller.rb`

Finally here are a bunch of autoloads:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib",  "#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/statistics)

#Any test/dev specific load paths
if not Rails.env.production?
  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/spec/support)
  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/spec/support/builders)
  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/spec/support/modules)
  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/spec/support/utils)
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does it work when you define it within the module? eg. `module Portfolios; class BaseManageController < ApplicationController; end; end`

Comment: Nope.  Still fails with the same error

Comment: I hate those errors... did you try: `class Portfolios::CustomizeController < BaseManageController`

Comment: Is it only failing in RSpec or does it also fail when running rails in development?

Answer (score 2):

This error sometimes occurs when there is an exception raised when the class is defined. In this case, a runtime error may be occurring when attempting to define the class found in base_manage_controller.rb.

To verify this is the case, try stripping out everything from `base_manage_controller.rb`, except the class declaration:

```
class Portfolios::BaseManageController < ApplicationController
end
```

It should result in the specs running, but failing.

To find the runtime error, put everything back into the class, and load it from `script/console`, by calling `Portfolios::BaseManageController`. That will attempt to dynamically load the class, and raise the exception that prevents your class from being defined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that `Portfolios` is not defined when `rspec` is loading `Portfolios::BaseManageController`.  Where did you define `Portfolios`?  If it's defined as a module or class somewhere in a separate file, you need to `require` this file first.

Answer (score 0):

there is a collision in your autoload path because of the existence of a file with the same name at  /var/lib/jenkins/.../portfolios/base_manage_controller.rb

You need to either modify your load path so app/controllers comes up earlier in the list or the file specified at the path above should be renamed or removed.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution will help you

create spec in following path for app/controllers/portfolios/base_manage_controller.rb
**spec/controllers/portfolios/base_manage_controller_spec.rb**

The spec content should be like this

```
describe Portfolios::BaseManageController do
 -----
end
```

You can apply the same logic for app/controllers/portfolios/customize_controller.rb